# Is there a way to take user input and match it to a value PYTHON SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database

So I made a database to store employees, my values in my database are:

- Eno (employee id)
- frame (first name)
- salary
- sex (male or female)

I'm trying to update the data from python input to my sql database.
So basically I'm asking the user to select the Eno from the list (showing row in database)
and if their input is a valid Eno then the database will pull up the information about that Employee. **My code so far is as follows:**

```
change = input("Enter the Employee Number To Make Changes") 
mycursor.execute("SELECT Eno FROM Employees WHERE 10 <= 15")
record = mycursor.fetchall()'                                
for x in record:                                           
    print(x)
```

**My output is:**

```
Enter the Employee Number To Make Changes
(36,)
(37,)
(38,)
(39,)
(40,)
```

Appreciate all help!

Comment: `database` is a generic concept, what's your DBMS, each of them has own proper dialects..?

Comment: External Dmbs, using sql to store data interpreted from user input in python3

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires more information, assuming that everything works fine. You can update your data using:

```py
cursor.execute('''
                UPDATE DatabaseName.TableName
                SET frame = 'DV', salary = 'DV', sex = 'DV'
                WHERE Eno = 'required employee id'
                ''')
conn.commit()
```

where **DV** refers to your **Desired Value**, hope it helps.

Comment: I had that execution working perfect but, I came to a situation when if there was two users named Ryan, it would change them both. my approach was to select the duplicate user and distinguish between their id for change

Comment: I think your problem is more a DB design, make sure that your primary key is the person's id `Eno` and not the name `frame`, since duplicate names is kind of a common situations in most tables and is highly discouraged to rely on. 

**HINT**: 
you can get the duplicate names using


`SELECT * FROM.TableName WHERE Eno = 'required employee id'`

And then do the update based what this query returns. @RyanO'Riordan

Comment: Glad it helped, kindly click on the green check mark to help the community find the answer shortly.

Comment: Okay so I don’t really know how to put this into words but here I go. So as all my employees are in the database table with their attributes fname salary sex, for example if I wanted to change john’s sex from male to female, how would I go about that bevause currently it’s changing every male to female when I execute the code

Comment: If It's changing every male to female make sure that: 1) your Primary Key is the id 2) you have **Unique** Id for each employer. If that doesn't help kindly post a two rows example of your DB. @RyanO'Riordan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you're trying to update your SQL database from your python script.

To get your list of valid entries you'll want to extract the employee numbers from the tuples.

```
change = input("Enter the Employee Number To Make Changes") 
mycursor.execute("SELECT Eno FROM Employees WHERE 10 <= 15")
record = mycursor.fetchall()'                                
records = [str(x[0]) for x in record]

# Check valid entry
if change in records:
   # Set up a dictionary
   changes = dict()
   fields = ["frame","salary","sex"]
   for f in fields:
      value = input("{}: ".format(f))
      changes[f] = value
   # Do the SQL stuff
   mycursor.execute("""
      UPDATE Employees
      SET {} = {}, {} = {}, {} = {}
      WHERE Eno = {}
      """.format(fields[0],changes[fields[0],fields[1],changes[fields[1],fields[2],changes[fields[2],change))

else:
   # insert some error handling...
```

... or something along those lines.

Does it help?

Comment: omg that's acc a really good concept. only other error I'm getting in the sql is.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{} = {}, {} = {}, {} = {} WHERE Eno = {}' at line 1

Comment: Check the SQL statement is creating what it should do as a string, I didn’t check that bit I must admit